# Seed Play Framework database from file

Tags: playframework, sbt

I have a file with 1.5 MB of data I would like to be loaded to one table in my Play Framework (2.x, scala) App's database before the app is run.  What is the best way to do this?  Should it be done during the build, via SBT, or should it be done when the application is started via `GlobalSettings.onStart`?

The file is CSV format but I'm looking for a strategy independent of file type.  I'm trying to find the most sensible solution.  Here is my reasoning so far:

### Build.sbt

Pros:

- The file is in the project repository, but not in the build output.
- The app starts faster.

Cons:

- Putting DB seed logic in the build file. Is this bad?
- More build settings & tasks to manage

### Global.onStart()

Pros:

- Project builds faster

Cons:

- Application takes longer to start, even if the project wasn't rebuilt
- More config settings to manage
- The seed file is part of the app, even though it isn't used at runtime.

Comment: What do you mean a 1.5MB file? An SQL file or something? Something else?

Comment: I mean a .csv file, but generally I just mean a file that would have to be parsed and transformed before adding to the database.